# How to log a circle in the console with a given radius?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I am trying to make a function that draws a circle in the console with a symbol of my choice, for example: '*', here is the wanted result:

```
drawCircle(5); //now I want to draw a circle with a radius of 5

    **
 *      *
*        *
 *       *
  *    *
    **
//this is a very ugly circle, but you probably get my idea.
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
const drawCirle = (radius) =>{
    const thickness = 0.4;
    const symbol = '*';
    const rin = radius - thickness
    const rout = radius + thickness;
    for(let y = radius; y >= -radius; --y){
        for(let x = -radius; x < rout; x += 0.5){
            let value = x * x + y * y;
            if(value >= rin * rin  && value <= rout * rout){
                console.log(symbol);

            }
            else{
                console.log(" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my head, this should be working, but it just logs a bunch of symbols randomly, just like that:

```
*

*
*

*
*
*
// and so on...
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong and if you have suggestions for a better algorithm I'll be glad.
P.S. I want to make it in javascript, so it works in the browser.

Comment: console.log is always adding the log as new line. So you should first figure out what comes on each line and then print them one by one.

Comment: Most probably console.log sends a newline every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each console log is printed in next row so you have to store whole row in for example single variable and print it after you have whole row.

```js
const drawCircle = (radius) => {
    const thickness = 0.4;
    const symbol = '*';
    const rin = radius - thickness
    const rout = radius + thickness;
    for (let y = radius; y >= -radius; --y) {
        let string = '';
        for (let x = -radius; x < rout; x += 0.5) {
            const value = x * x + y * y;
            if (value >= rin * rin && value <= rout * rout) {
                string += symbol;
            } else {
                string += " ";
            }
        }
        console.log(string);
    }
}
drawCircle(5);
```